# Umbraco 7 - Read Only property on Umbraco doc type

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco6, umbraco-blog

I want to have a property on a doc type that is read-only (Via the Umbraco UI), I want to populate its value after the umbraco event 'Saved'

Its going to be a string, but I don't want a text box for the user to edit it.

Any ideas

Comment: How is this question unclear? Simple question, simple answer.

Comment: agree, question is very clear, I am upvoting it now because question was very helpful for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out there is a label data type, seems like I missed it, silly me.